# Cross compiler for Windows on PowerPC or Dec Alpha

Tags: windows, compiler

Today it is possible to compile dlls using winAPI for ARM and ARM64. But those compilers doesn’t support deprecated targets.
I mean, Windows *(not CE)* and visual studio supported Alpha; PowerPC; Mips and IA64 in the past. While it restricts to outdated Windows® versions, getting those is the best way to run desktop windows apps if you have the source code.

My idea is to support those platforms without having to use several compilers versions.